# Coercing dictionary values into floats

Tags: python, string, dictionary, numbers, typeerror

I'm new to python. I'm having an issue, and I'm stuck. Information is saved in a number of dictionaries. the variable pos is a float in the file, but python reads it as a string. I suppose this is why when `compare_positions` function is called, I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "anotherPythontry.py", line 167, in <module>
  iterate_thru(Genes,c,maxp,p)
File "anotherPythontry.py", line 133, in iterate_thru
  compare_positions(test_position,maxp,sn,g,p,c)
File "anotherPythontry.py", line 103, in compare_positions
  elif (testpos > maxpos and testpos <= maxpos+1):
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

I've tried making `pos`, `testpos`, `maxpos` floats, but then I get `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number`. I'm not sure what the problem is.

Here is the code:

```
def hasher():
      return collections.defaultdict(hasher)

Positions = hasher()
LODs = hasher()
whole_line = hasher()
InCommon = hasher()

def save_info(line):
    lod = line[7]
    chr = line[2]
    pos = line[3] #is a float in the file. Is read as a string though
    snp = line[1]
    item = line[10]
    together = '\t'.join(line)
    whole_line[item][snp]=together
    Positions[item][chr][snp]= pos
    LODs[item][chr][snp]=lod
    return snp, item

with open(sys.argv[3],"r") as geneFile:
    gsnp_list = list()
    Genes = []
    for line in geneFile:
            line = line.strip().split("\t")
            type1 = line[0]
            if "SNP_id" or "Minimum" not in line:
                    if type1 == match:
                            snp,item = save_info(line)
                            gsnp_list.append(snp)
                            if item not in Genes:
                                    Genes.append(item)
# A similar block of code is for another file with phenotypes

def compare_positions(testpos,maxsnp,gs,gene,p,c):
    maxpos = Positions[p][c].get(maxsnp)
    if testpos == maxpos:
            InCommon[p][c][maxsnp][gene].append(gs) 
    elif (testpos > maxpos and testpos <= maxpos+1):
            InCommon[p][c][maxsnp][gene].append(gs)
    elif (testpos < maxpos and testpos >= maxpos-1):
            InCommon[p][c][maxsnp][gene].append(gs)

def iterate_thru(Genelist,c,maxp,p):
    for g in Genelist:
            for sn in Positions[g][c].keys():
                    test_position = Positions[g][c].get(sn)
                    compare_positions(test_position,maxp,sn,g,p,c)

for g in Genes: 
    for c in Positions[g].keys():
            chr_SNPlist = ()
            chr_SNPlist = [snp for snp in gsnp_list if snp == Positions[g][c].keys()]
            maxp = get_max(chr_SNPlist,g,c)
            iterate_thru(Phenos,c,maxp,g)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line:

```
test_position = Positions[g][c].get(sn)
```

The given request is not in the dictionary, returning `None` as a result which cannot be compared to an integer.  This value is then passed to the `compare_positions` method where the comparison is made that has resulted in your error.

Depending on your application, you may try a default value such as zero:

```
test_position = Positions[g][c].get(sn, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I mistakingly didn't add all of the code before. As you can see the `test_position = Positions[g][c].get(sn)` should be in the dictionary because I'm iterating through its keys in the `iterate_thru` function. In the `save_info` function, the dictionary should undergo autovivification.

Comment: If the key is in the dictionary, then the value for that key must be None.  This might work `test_position = Positions[g][c].get(sn) or 0` where the value zero will be returned if None is the value for that key location.